# Android and firebase-database

Tags: android, mysql, firebase-realtime-database

Can we keep storing data under a single column(if there is any) in firebase-database, for suppose , like in MySQL, there is a column called latitude we can keep storing/updating new data/latitude coordinates in the next row keeping the older ones and so on from a single user. Likewise, can we do it in Firebase-database? If so, how?

Comment: Typos tend to be frowned upon.  Typos of well known brand names doubly so.  Typos of well known brand names *in the title of the question* quadruply so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: The structure does support something similar to columns where you can add new data.

Like **ofalvai** writes, Firebase is different from MySQL in that it's not table based but more like a JSON tree. So technically there aren't really tables with columns and rows. It's more like an array of arrays. So what you can do is create an "array" called latitude that stores data which you can keep adding to.

Adding to a child called latitude would look something like this on android:

```
private void updateLatitude(String latitudeID, LatitudeCoordinates latitude_coordinates) {
  mDatabase.child("latitude").child(latitudeID).setValue(latitude_coordinates);
}
```

Where LatitudeCoordinates is a class, latitude is the parent, latitudeID is a unique value for each latitude coordinate.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write 
Shows in detail how to communicate with a Firebase database

Comment: Thank you so much Frederik and ofalvai.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database is more like a JSON tree, rather than a relational database. Take a look at [their documentation on how to (and not to) structure your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).